# QNX LibPcap packet filter usage for IEC61850 Goose layer2 messages capture

Tags: libpcap, qnx

I am trying use QNX (using QNX7.1) based PCAP API calls to transmit and receive the IEC61850 Goose (Datalink layer based) messages.

I could able to transmit Goose messages successfully through API calls (pcap_inject()), but not able to receive goose messages through PCAP calls (Tried pcap_loop/pcap_next/pcap_dispatch API calls).

I tried to use different filter options like ether src addr/len >=/len<=, it is able to capture other messages on wire ( EGD/UDP/TCP..with len or src addr filtering)....as I understand PCAP filter is not understanding the particular Goose protocol to capture.

If any one come across similar situation, could you please help me out.

I tried to use different filter options like ether src addr/len >=/len<=, it is able to capture other messages on wire ( EGD/UDP/TCP..with len or src addr filtering)....as I understand PCAP filter is not understanding the particular Goose protocol to capture.

If any one come across similar situation, could you please help me out.